# Does my MySQL design violate database rules?

Tags: mysql

I need an advice if i am doing the right thing at MySQL database.  I am connecting this database which i named **inventory** to a java application, this consist of a table named **item** and here are the details:

1. **id** - int(11), AUTO_INCREMENT
2. **item_name** - varchar(50)
3. **category** - varchar(25)
4. **q_box** - int(11)
5. **unit_price_box** - double
6. **sub_total_box** - double
7. **q_pc** - int(11)
8. **unit_price_pc** - double
9. **sub_total_pc** - double
10. **grand_total** - double
11. **recent_date_purchased** - date
12. **last_date_modified** - timestamp

I am already using this to store stocks in the development of an inventory application, but what i want to do now is to add a table which will store orders from customers.

I am planning to do this:

table name: **orders**

which consists of the following:

1. **order_id** - int(11), AUTO_INCREMENT
2. **item_name** - varchar(50)
3. **category** - varchar(25)
4. **q_box** - int(11)
5. **unit_price_box** - double //this is the retail/wholesale price per box
6. **sub_total_box** - double
7. **q_pc** - int(11)
8. **unit_price_pc** - double  //this is the retail/wholesale price per pc
9. **sub_total_pc** - double
10. **grand_total** - double
11. **customer_name** - varchar(50)
12. **last_date_modified** - timestamp

    My question is:  Am I violating any MySQL rules since I am using a same variable?

or do you have any advice? Any advice would be highly appreciated..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off with the **items** table, as well as an **orders** and **order_items** table.

**orders**

```
id int(11), AUTO_INCREMENT
customerid int(11)
orderdate datetime
PRIMARY KEY (id)
FOREIGN KEY (customerid) REFERENCES Customers(Id)
```

**order_items**

```
orderid int(11),
itemid int(11)
FOREIGN KEY (orderid) REFERENCES Orders(id)
FOREIGN KEY (itemid) REFERENCES Items(Id)
```

That way there is less repeated data.

Answer (score 2):

Your design could use some normalization, you have a lot of data that is repeated, which goes against the whole idea of relational databases such as MySQL.

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/

Comment: It's worth noting that strictly, no, your design doesn't violate any MySQL rules - or, even, database rules. You don't _have_ to normalize your data. However, in terms of data optimization to avoid anomalies, you should redesign your schema.

Answer (score 1):

In the **order** table, you can have Customer_Id and make that Foreign Key.
As Customer should be there before you create an Order for him/her.

No you wont be violating the rules of MYSQL if you use the same variables,

When you write a  JOINS, then you need to make use of Alias to identify and NOT to get CONFUSED